# How do I sniff Z-Wave packets with a Zulu Transceiver

Tags: wireless, sniffer

I'm trying to sniff the communication between Z-Wave devices. I have set up a "smart home" consisting of a few devices using Z-Wave technology, which use the frequency 868 MHz. I have been told that I'm able to both receive and send packets with the use of a Zulu v1.0 transceiver which is based on the Silicon Labs Si1000 chipset ([datasheet for Zulu v1.0](http://www.rfsolutions.co.uk/acatalog/DS-ZULU-2.pdf)).

General questions:

1. Is it possible to sniff the packets sent with the tools that I got? I got a restricted budget so I can not buy any more tools sadly.
2. Is there anyone who has done this before? Any pointers?
3. Anyone know where I can find the library for the chipset?

Another problem I've encountered is that I can't confirm that the chip actually works (I've borrowed the zulu-chip). When installing the IDE several example projects are included. I've tried to run a project, called "Blinky" which is supposed to get a yellow led to flash, but I've had no success of getting it to work. The connection between the chip and the computer through the USB Debug adapter is successful since the there is no problem compiling the code or executing it (the run-led on the adapter switches to green when running the code on the IDE).

Any thoughts or directions? Anything is appreciated I've been stuck for a while and I believe this is one of my last resorts.

Thank you for taking your time and reading this.

Comment: first step sounds like it would be to get the chip working, i.e. the blinky light and what not - perhaps another stack site would be able to help with that (EE? SO? not sure)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because hardware configurations isn't really our wavelength.  Migration to Electrical Engineering SE might give better results.